# MultiObjective Optimization using R Software

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm facing with a large scale `multi-objective` optimization problem, after a long search I have not found any useful package in R.

Please help me in this regard and i am not restricted to any particular method. Please tell me if there is any package in R using which I can solve Multi-Objective Mathematical Programming Problems.

Comment: By "mathematical programming problems" do you mean MIP or LP problems ? If they're large I suggest you to use a commercial sw like CPLEX (there are 2 packages interfacing to cplex in R, Rcplex and cplexAPI). As far as multiobjective is concerned I think you should do it by hand, so solve the first objective, then put the objective as a constraint in the second solve and so on...

Comment: Take a look at [https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), surely you'll find something.